# NodeMCU cannot get MQTT and Led strip script work together

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am trying to configure a NodeMCU v1 (with led driver board) to control a ledstrip with MQTT,
First I started with controlling the led strip.
for this I've used the LEDStripDriver package which has some example code which I minified, but still works:

```
#include "RGBdriver.h"
#define CLK 3//pins definitions for the driver        
#define DIO 2
RGBdriver Driver(CLK,DIO);
void setup()  
{ 

}  
void loop()  
{ 
  /*Function: SetColor()                              */
  /*Parameters: red:0~255                           */
  /*            green:0~255                         */
  /*            blue:0~255                          */
  /*Note: the greater the value,the brighter the LED*/
  Driver.begin();
  Driver.SetColor(100, 0, 0); //Red
  Driver.end();
  delay(5000);
  // other colors
  Driver.begin();
  Driver.SetColor(0, 0, 0);//all LED is off
  Driver.end();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Uploading this to the NodeMCU works perfectly and the led turns from red to off as expected, so my wiring is correct.

next I took an example for the MQTT library I used, this is the example code I've used:
https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/examples/mqtt_esp8266/mqtt_esp8266.ino
and merged the rgb ledstrip code into this, with the following result:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <RGBdriver.h> // Including the RGBdriver package as in the example
#define CLK 3//pins definitions for the driver        
#define DIO 2

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "WIFI";
const char* password = "Password";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.x";

const int mqtt_port = 1883;
const char* mqtt_user = "username";
const char* mqtt_password = "password";

RGBdriver Driver(CLK,DIO); // here I placed the RGB driver initiator
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    Serial.println("LED STRIP TO ON");
    Driver.begin();
    Driver.SetColor(0, 0, 100); //Blue when mqtt receives value of 1
    Driver.end();
  } else {
    Serial.println("LED STRIP TO OFF");
    Driver.begin();
    Driver.SetColor(0, 0, 0);//all LED off when mqtt receives value of 0
    Driver.end();
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str(), mqtt_user, mqtt_password)) { // changed this from the example to enable login with username/password
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("outTopic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  //pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {
  // This is copied directly from the example, so I expected this at least to work
  Driver.begin();
  Driver.SetColor(100, 0, 0); //Red
  Driver.end();
  delay(5000);
  // other colors
  Driver.begin();
  Driver.SetColor(0, 0, 0);//all LED is off
  Driver.end();
  delay(5000);
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  client.loop();

  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, MSG_BUFFER_SIZE, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("outTopic", msg);
  }
}
```

When I upload the code above, it connects to the Wifi and MQTT server, and it does publish it's messages, also it subscribes to the inTopic and responds to it, as seen in the following serial log:

```
Connecting to WIFI
scandone
scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 4
cnt 

connected with WIFI, channel 6
dhcp client start...
.....ip:192.168.1.47,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.1.1
.
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.1.47
Attempting MQTT connection...connected
Publish message: hello world #1
Publish message: hello world #2
Publish message: hello world #3
Publish message: hello world #4
pm open,type:2 0
Publish message: hello world #5
Message arrived [inTopic] 1
LED STRIP TO ON
Publish message: hello world #6
Publish message: hello world #7
Message arrived [inTopic] 0
LED STRIP TO OFF
Publish message: hello world #8
```

so also the MQTT works as expected, and the network info is configured correctly,
however the led strip turns to white the moment I start uploading from arduino IDE, and never changes it's color, also when I publish 1 or 0 to inTopic.
if I cycle all power from both led strip and nodemcu, the led strip stays off untill I re-upload the script.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as why both scrips are working independedly, but led stops working when combined?